# Software for Braid Groups

Tags: group-theory, math-software, online-resources, computational-algebra, braid-groups

I am looking for software/online tool that works on Braid Groups. I am aware that there are resources that allows you to draw braids by imputing generators or detect whether two braids are equivalent or not. I am looking for a more "interactive" one. Namely, after drawing a braid, I am hoping to drag the strings to form a new (equivalent) braid by myself. If I can manually click on an over-crossing and switch it to an under-crossing or vice versa that would be ideal.

Anyone knows such a software/online tool, or knows the non-existence?

Comment: This series of animated movies on Braids show some of these operations you talk about  http://matematita.science.unitn.it/braids/index.html.
May be you can contact the creator for help, here is her web page http://science.unitn.it/~dalvit/

Comment: This could be helpful: http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/knots/sage/knots/link.html